# Read a remote MS Access database C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I need to get a connection string from a remote location to access my MS Access database. I know you can do this like:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Temp\\Testdatabase.accdb");
```

So I need to know how to access a file if it were hosted. So the source would be http://somewebsite.com/Testdatabase.accdb

How do I do this?

Comment: I doubt if that will work. Maybe if that server has webdav enabled but with just http or ftp you're out of luck.

Comment: If I wanted to read/write data from my Access database remotely, what would be a good solution?

Comment: Put some sort of web interface/webapi in front of it or maybe see if [Data Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792(v=vs.110).aspx) is an option.

Comment: Good solution? Not to use Access, its not designed for remote connections.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple: You can't do this.

Access needs an SMB fileshare which you can't get from a web server. Neither can you attach a database file from an FTP server, OneDrive, or DropBox.

So either convert the remote database to a server engine like SQL Server or MySQL, or (if you only need to read) download the Access file to a local drive.